# How do I correctly use is_single to hide my array?

Tags: arrays, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization

I can remove WP hooks globally but when I try to remove them on specific pages my code does not work. I learned today that I must use a conditional statement to achieve this and after a long and continuous search, I think I should use the "is_single tag" with an array to make this happen. I am using product IDs in the array.

How should I place the conditional tag and array in my code?

I have tried to place the array inside the function without success.

This is the code which removes the hook globally:

```
function remove_woo_commerce_hooks() {
    global $avada_woocommerce;

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( 
        $avada_woocommerce, 'output_related_products' ), 15 );

}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_commerce_hooks' );
```

This is what I have done without success to remove the hook only on pages in the array:

```
function remove_woo_commerce_hooks() {
    global $avada_woocommerce;
    if ( is_single( array(20031, 17222))) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( 
        $avada_woocommerce, 'output_related_products' ), 15 );
    }
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_commerce_hooks' );
```

I expect the code to remove related_products from the pages identified in the array.

When I add the array I don't receive any errors and the output on the pages are unchanged. It still shows related_products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use is_single but check if the post ID is included in your array of post IDs.
If your function fires on 'after_setup_theme' you still can't get the global $post variable, so I would try with 'template_redirect'.

```
function remove_woo_commerce_hooks() {
    global $avada_woocommerce,$post;
    if ( is_object( $post ) && in_arry( $post->ID,array( 20031,17222 ) ) ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', array( 
        $avada_woocommerce, 'output_related_products' ), 15 );
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'remove_woo_commerce_hooks' );
```